# how to print pcb using uv exposure

Tags: pcb

I want to check am doing this correctly before I waste a piece o pcb. I exported the image of my pcb then then I copied and pasted the image into a new document. Therefore I have two copies side by side then printed it onto transparencies. I've cut them out and stapled them together. Is the side with the ink (not the smooth side) I want pressed againest the uv coating on the board?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it either way round and get good results, but I think for the best results use the ink side to the copper. This makes light less likely to "get underneath".
Make sure you have your printer set to highest resolution and use the transparency setting - this sets it to a higher temperature to ensure the ink sticks. FWIW, tracing paper actually works best in my experience.

Comment: Thanks for your infoation. I was wondering if you could use paper. Since everyone used transparencies, I just stuck with it. They freaking expensive from the shops.

Answer (score 1):

If you place the transparency on the PCB you should see the layout as seen from the soldering side. Usually you'll create your layout from the component side, so this should be the *mirror image* of that. (I always put text on the copper layer, like an identification number and revision, and they should appear readable.)

Comment: Thanks for replying. But Oliver gave me so other useful information.